# Wait for signal to start activity (amazon Workflow)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, workflow, aws-sdk, amazon-swf

I have built a workflow using java flow framework provided by AWS. I have created 4 activities. First activity wait for signal to start. Then all the activities execute synchronously using Promise<> object. Workflow implementation code is following-

```
public class PaginationWorkflowImpl implements PaginationWorkflow 
{  
private ManualUploadClient operations0 = new ManualUploadClientImpl();
   private DownloadActivityClient operations1 = new DownloadActivityClientImpl();
   private ConvertActivityClient operations2 = new ConvertActivityClientImpl();
   private UploadActivityClient operations3 = new UploadActivityClientImpl();
   final Settable<String> result = new Settable<String>();

   public void paginate() 
   {
     Promise<String> UDone = operations0.Upload(result);
     Promise<String> dnDone = operations1.s3Download(UDone);
     Promise<String> convDone = operations2.pdfToTiff(dnDone);
     operations3.s3Upload(convDone);
   }

   @Override
   public void signal1(String data)  {
      // result.set(data);
       //result.Void();
       Promise<String> ready = Promise.asPromise("ready");
       result.chain(ready);
   }


}
```

Here activity Upload wait for the object result to be in ready state. So when I signal workflow the method signal1 kicks off and puts the object in ready state.
But as soon as I signal the workflow, workflow execution get failed.

I am using nodejs aws api to signal workflow. Below is the code for the same-

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '', secretAccessKey: ''});
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var swf = new AWS.SWF();
var params = {
  domain: 'HWdemo2', /* required */
  signalName: 'signal1', /* required */
  workflowId: 'PaginationWorkflow', /* required */
  //input: 'true'
  //runId: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
swf.signalWorkflowExecution(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

And the error which I is showing in AWS workflow events console for execution fail is following-

```js
["java.util.concurrent.CancellationException", {
  "cause": ["java.lang.NullPointerException", {
    "cause": null,
    "stackTrace": [{
      "methodName": "<init>",
      "fileName": null,
      "lineNumber": -1,
      "className": "java.io.StringReader",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "createParser",
      "fileName": "JsonFactory.java",
      "lineNumber": 835,
      "className": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "readValue",
      "fileName": "ObjectMapper.java",
      "lineNumber": 2098,
      "className": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "fromData",
      "fileName": "JsonDataConverter.java",
      "lineNumber": 96,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.JsonDataConverter",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "signalRecieved",
      "fileName": "POJOWorkflowDefinition.java",
      "lineNumber": 111,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "doExecute",
      "fileName": "AsyncDecider.java",
      "lineNumber": 417,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider$1",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "",
      "fileName": "",
      "lineNumber": 0,
      "className": "--- continuation ---",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "handleWorkflowExecutionSignaled",
      "fileName": "AsyncDecider.java",
      "lineNumber": 413,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "processEvent",
      "fileName": "AsyncDecider.java",
      "lineNumber": 251,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "decide",
      "fileName": "AsyncDecider.java",
      "lineNumber": 496,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "handleDecisionTask",
      "fileName": "AsyncDecisionTaskHandler.java",
      "lineNumber": 50,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecisionTaskHandler",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "pollAndProcessSingleTask",
      "fileName": "DecisionTaskPoller.java",
      "lineNumber": 201,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionTaskPoller",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "run",
      "fileName": "GenericWorker.java",
      "lineNumber": 94,
      "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericWorker$PollServiceTask",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "runWorker",
      "fileName": null,
      "lineNumber": -1,
      "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "run",
      "fileName": null,
      "lineNumber": -1,
      "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }, {
      "methodName": "run",
      "fileName": null,
      "lineNumber": -1,
      "className": "java.lang.Thread",
      "nativeMethod": false
    }],
    "message": null,
    "localizedMessage": null,
    "suppressed": ["[Ljava.lang.Throwable;", []]
  }],
  "stackTrace": [{
    "methodName": "execute",
    "fileName": "POJOWorkflowDefinition.java",
    "lineNumber": 66,
    "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOWorkflowDefinition",
    "nativeMethod": false
  }, {
    "methodName": "doAsync",
    "fileName": "AsyncDecider.java",
    "lineNumber": 70,
    "className": "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider$WorkflowExecuteAsyncScope",
    "nativeMethod": false
  }],
  "message": null,
  "localizedMessage": null,
  "suppressed": ["[Ljava.lang.Throwable;", []]
}]
```

Can anyone please help me out with this error, Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default workflow execution fails if it cannot deserialize the signal arguments. By default [JsonDataConverter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/JsonDataConverter.html) is used by workflow decider which is implemented on top of [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). It expects JSON document in a specific format. The simplest way to learn this format is to send signal using the generated Java interface and look at the workflow history. Then you can just reproduce it in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for reply, I also used java sdk to send signal then it was the same problem of workflow execution failure. The error was                                "com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.DataConverterException",{"cause":["com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException "]}"   Can you please point out to some documents or links which can be useful. Thanks

Comment: What was the content of the signal field as it appeared in the history?

Comment: Signal content from workflow history is following -                                                               {  
         EventTimestamp:         Fri Apr 03 15:33:26         IST 2015,
         EventType:WorkflowExecutionSignaled,
         EventId:5,
         WorkflowExecutionSignaledEventAttributes:{  
            SignalName:signal1,
            Input:data,
            ExternalInitiatedEventId:0
         },

      },

Answer (score 0):

The workflow expects an input of array of objects which can be converted to string as json.